# Angular2 - exportar un file que se obtiene de un api rest

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Tengo un api rest que me genera un archivo y genera la descarga. Este api, yo lo llamo desde el browser y el archivo se descarga y lo puedo abrir y tiene el contenido correcto. Ahora bien...necesito llamarlo desde una app angular2.
Mi servicio es el siguiente:

```
public Download = (): Observable<Blob> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + "sdownload", {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .map((response: Response) => {
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

En mi component tengo:

```
onExport(): void {

    this.serviceUser
        .Download()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.downloadfile(data);
            }),
        error => {
                    console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('download usuarios finalizado');
        };
}

downloadfile(data: any) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    console.log(blob);
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Al ejecutar este codigo, se descarga un archivo que lo unico contiene adentro es la palabra "Undefined". Me podrán dar una mano?...mil gracias de antemano!

Comment: Añade console log y muestranos que recibes.
.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
             this.downloadfile(data);
            }),

Comment: En la consola solo recibo "Undefined".

Comment: Pues tu llamada al api está mal, testeala primero desde un cliente como postman y asegurate que funciona

Comment: @AlejandroLora podrias indicarme cual es la parte del api que está mal?...si yo al api lo llamo desde el browser me descarga el archivo...si lo llamo desde angular2 no lo hace...osea, no entiendo cual es la parte que está mal o no la veo

Comment: No he dicho que tu API este mal, he dicho la forma en la que la estas llamando, tu llamada a la api, por eso, de testear con un cliente como postman y no con el browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, despues de tanto andar, encontré el problema!...estaba aca...me faltaba esta linea (la tercera, donde hace el response.blob() ):

```
public Download = (): Observable<Blob> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + "sdownload", {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .map((response: Response) => response.blob())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Gracias igual a los que hicieron el comentarios!